# Yahoo Finance Beta Calculation - foreign stock

Tags: beta

How does Yahoo Finance calculate Beta for stocks quotes in foreign markets? Does it consider the volatility against local markets indexes or US S&P 500?

Answer (score 1):

A "correct" way would be to use each country's index, such as DAX for German stocks or CAC-40 for French stocks; and to regress total return (including dividends) in local currency (i.e. not USD-denominated return of an ADR). I took a quick look at Yahoo Finance and they don't seem to document what they do.